# БЭМ правильно ли внутрь блока вставлять блок в названии которого нет упоминания о родителе

Tags: html, бэм

Собственно вопрос - правильно ли внутрь блока вставлять блок в названии которого нет упоминания о родителе, ну, к примеру, есть код:

```
<div class="reviews__header">
    <div class="custom-select">
        <select><option>Опция 1</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. можно ли так делать при условии, что берется за правило БЭМ методология.

Или мне обязательно надо добавить на блок родителя класс `reviews-header`, а затем на блок с селектом класс `reviews-header__select`, тем самым указав на то, что данный селект является дочерним элементом? И тогда код примет вид:

```
 <div class="reviews__header reviews-header">
      <div class="custom-select reviews-header__select">
          <select><option>Опция 1</option></select>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В БЭМ у блоков не бывает никаких "родителей", а значит их нет необходимости как-то специально упоминать.

Поэтому исходно предложенная вами структура совершенно нормальна.

Только не забывайте, что блокам нельзя назначать правила позиционирования (position, display, top, left, right, bottom, margin и подобные).